# Clickable List on homepage

Tags: lists, hyperlinks

When creating a list that you wish to  be a display of clickable links to a full page of more detailed information, what is a good way to display this?  In the Balsamiq example below, is a sketch of the basic list.  I want to use a more attractive look than the blue underlined text, and had a suggestion of a shaded background like in the 3rd and 4th list items.  What is a good way to display the clickable list?

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxQeuo.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't break user expectations.

Users will expect links to look like links - and that means displaying them in blue with an underline and changing the cursor to a hand when the mouse is over the link.

If you really don't want your links to look like links, then you still need to make it obvious that they are a clickable entity. The other element that fulfils this criteria is a button, so your 3rd and 4th items would probably be OK.

You *might* get away with just changing the cursor, but people won't necessarily think of moving the cursor over the link if it doesn't look like a link or a button.